# Programmatically changing button label in Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, xib

I made a .xib with a button, and referenced it with an outlet to "btnActies"

when i do the following (at any given time) in the back-end C# code

> btnActies.TitleLabel.Text = "This is a
>   new label!";

When i build and run the app, the label on the button changes to "This is a new label", 
but then, if I touch the button, the label reverts to the 'default' text i set in the .xib file.

How do i change the label on a Monotouch UIButton and keep this from happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you want to set some text on a UIButton, you do not do it by altering the text of its TextLabel property. You do it by calling its SetTitle method, passing as the second argument, the button state for which the title will be set at runtime. Chetan Bhalara's answer is correct, here is the C#/MonoTouch equivalent:

```
btnActies.SetTitle ("title", UIControlState.Normal);
```

They way you are doing it right now doesn't work, because the label's text is changing internally whenever needed, to the title set in Interface Builder (if you have set it), in this case when you tap the button.

Answer (score 0):

//Improved Formatting

Hello

You can use this code for change the button label for iPhone.

```
[btnActies.setTitle:@"Title value1" forState:UIButtonStateNormal];

[btnActies.setTitle:@"Title value2" forState:UIButtonStateSelected];

[btnActies.setTitle:@"Title value3" forState:UIButtonStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the label from C# (MonoTouch), and these look like Quartz definitions. I am trying to find a way to do it from C#

Comment: Means you want to change the button label of iPhone from C#?

Comment: Correct. 
The button labels have numbers on them, which i fetch through a webservice in C#. so i want to update the button labels from C#.

Comment: Ok, Then you need to parse the data from web service and then you can pass it as label.

Comment: That is what i did. (see the initial post)
But once i interact with the button, the label is reset.

Comment: First, create web service that retrive data using web service. Make sure it display all the data in xml format or json format.

Then parse that data using NSXMLParser or JSON Parser.

Comment: I made the webservice, the data is being retreived, this is not at all relevant to the question.

Comment: can i speak on any other messenger? Because, I can't explain in detail in comments.

Comment: Yes, monotouch only exists for iPhone

Comment: Monotouch from Novell allows devlopment in C# on IOS devices. if you want more information, see [link](http://monotouch.net/)